# CSS (transition) after a pseudo element - how to transition content that shows on hover

Tags: css, css-transitions

```css
div {
  transition: after 3s;
  -webkit-transition: after 3s;
}

div:hover:after {
  content: "- positive!";
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```

---

I have this sample code above. I'm trying to use 'transition' so that the text: '- positive!' takes 3 seconds to slide/show up. But it isn't working.. How to fix it?

Answer (score 64):

`after` is not a valid value of `transition`.

Instead put `transition` as a property of the `:after` selector.

```css
div:after {
  content: " - positive!";
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s;
  transition: all 3s;
}

div:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```

You can also have a different transition on the hover in and hover out state. This allows us to have a delay to show the pseudo-element but no delay to hide it.

```css
div:after {
  content: " - positive!";
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms;
  transition: all 250ms;
}

div:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s;
  transition: all 3s;
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```

Here is a list of browsers that support transitions on pseudo elements:
http://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/

Comment: Aye on the last statement. I think even recent (not the latest) version of Chrome may not have full support for transitions in pseudo-elements. The latest release does, tho :)

Comment: You can also have a different transition on the *hover* state and the *mouseout* state.  So there's a delay to show the pseudo-element, but no delay to hide it.  Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/vp8Pv/

Comment: @davidpauljunior Thanks for the suggestion. I've finally added this content into the answer.