# CSS Transition on the 'content' property of :before pseudo element

Tags: css

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/c4MNs/

Essentially I am swapping out the contents of the `content` property under the `i:before` pseudo which works fine. However, I am unable to force a transition such that this swap occurs smoothly.

I followed the advice found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19579514/765409

But you can see that this is not effective in this situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't apply transition to pseudo elements `content` property's content itself. You can apply transition to a pseudo element's opacity, width, height, its `content`'s font-size and many more properties... but not the `content` property's content.

Comment: Do you have any possible work arounds in mind to accomplish this? Doesn't have to be necessarily CSS. Chaining absolutely positioned elements to fadeToggle is one idea but from previous use this looks clunkier than a transition. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, you will need to build a custom one. fadeToggle can work too. You can build your own toggle with css transitions if you're not satisfied with let's say jQuery's fadeToggle or another library's similar functionalists.

Comment: Very nice ! Using opacity + width I can insert a nice svg icon within ::before content property.

Answer (score 1):

As @Arbel said:

> You can't apply transition to pseudo elements `content` property's
>   content itself. You can apply transition to a pseudo element's
>   opacity, width, height, its `content`'s font-size and many more
>   properties... but not the `content` property's content.

The [In-depth resource](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/#animatable-properties).

But, about your request for a workaround:

1. **Possibility #1:**

   [here](https://css-tricks.com/animating-the-content-property/) it is described a solution but, note, with a limited
   cross-browser compatibility:

   **HTML Code:**

   ```
   <div class="letter-changer"></div>
   ```

   **CSS Code:**

   ```
   @keyframes changeLetter {
     0% {
       content: "A";
     }
     50% {
       color: white;
     }
     100% {
       content: "B";
     }
   }

   .letter-changer::after {
     animation: changeLetter 3s linear infinite alternate;
   }
   ```

   [Demo](https://codepen.io/robinrendle/pen/dYmjKp)
2. **Possibility #2:**

   alternatively, you can sum `content` with other properties for which
   you can use a transition instead (like `text-shadow`), to distract the
   attention in a soft way (but not for `content`), like in this my
   [demo](https://codepen.io/ChemBioScripting/details/KBBMLM/).

Greetings

Answer (score -1):

Though the question was asked long ago but as I still faced the same problem so I needed to find solution which you can find here 
html

```
<div class="removeCampaign">
<i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
```

jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sh39nqpy/
Hope it will help those who is in need !

Comment: Your HTML is incomplete and your jsfiddle doesn't work. Please fix these mistakes.