# Transition not applying on hover CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to get the "::after" content defined for the ".projectBtn" element upon hovering it, **with a subtle transition**. However, I've tried applying the

```
transition: all 1s linear;
```

to ".projectBtn::after" as well as ".projectBtn" but it still shows up suddenly.

Here is the code -

CSS -

```
.projectFooter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 0.5em;
}
.projectTech {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  transition: all 2s linear;
  gap: 1em;
}
.projectBtn {
  background-color: inherit;
  transition: all 2s linear;
  color: inherit;
}

.projectBtn:hover::after {
  transition: all 2s linear;
  content: " This project is made with the help of ReactJS.";
}
```

JSX -

```
<div className="projectFooter">
            <div className="projectTech">
              <button className="projectBtn">
                <FaReact size={25} />
              </button>
            </div>

            <div className="projectGithub">
              <FiGithub size={18} />
            </div>
          </div>
```

Here is the screenshot of what it looks like.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not using any `transform` properties on your `::after` content.

Refer the code below. Hoping it might help you.

```css
button {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: .5rem;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
    font-size: 48px;
    color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
    position: relative;
    background: none;
}

button::after {
    content: 'This project is made using React';
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-30%) translateY(-50%);
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
}

button:hover::after {
     opacity: 1;
     transform:translateX(10%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<button>⚛</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, however, I'm not quite sure why it didn't work with the "content" attribute. CSS transitions allow you to change property (Not specific to transform) values smoothly, over a given duration. As I've used "All" it should also work with content. I've tried display: none; with .projectBtn::after and upon hovering, display: inline; But it doesn't work that way too. Any idea why it won't work?

Comment: Here's the answer to your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396621/css-transition-on-the-content-property-of-before-pseudo-element#:~:text=You%20can't%20apply%20transition,not%20the%20content%20property's%20content. And why also display properties did not work